# Add a frame to canvas in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Using Tkinter I have a Toplevel named self.edit_window, a Frame named frame and a Canvas named canvas. All I want to do is add the frame to the canvas, which I try to do by using the create_window method:

```
#make canvas
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self.edit_window) 

#make frame and add to canvas
frame = Tkinter.Frame()
canvas.create_window(0,0, anchor = Tkconstants.NW, window = frame, width = 200, height = 200)
```

And I get the following error on the create_window call:

```
TclError: can't use .173048428 in a window item of this canvas
```

And I have no idea what that means. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try anchor = NW?

Comment: Yes I did, the way I imported I have to add the Tkconstants to it.

Comment: anchor has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you supply does not give this error. Are you *certain* that code is enough to illustrate the problem?

That being said, the error you say you are getting is consistent with trying to add to a canvas a window that is not a sibling or child of the canvas. According to the official tk documentation:

> The window specified by pathName must either be a child of the canvas
>   widget or a child of some ancestor of the canvas widget. PathName may
>   not refer to a top-level window.

If you make your frame a child of the canvas, this problem will go away (though, strictly speaking, it doesn't have to be an immediate child).

Comment: This latter part answers it. As I said self.edit_window is a Tkinter.Toplevel. Since I did not specify any parent for the frame, self.edit_window is not an ancestor of frame. But I did specify the canvas as a child of self.edit_window. If I declare frame as: frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.edit_window), then now both frame and canvas have a common ancestor. Also note that if I declare canvas as canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root) where root is my main window, then it also works because the frame defaulted to a child of root since I did not pass it a parent.